# If interval contains a value return corresponding

Tags: excel

I have two tables

First:

```
ID  Text
AA  Example 1
BB  Example 2
CC  Example 3
```

Second:

```
ID       Text
132CC32  
112AA52  
142BB42
```

I need that in the second table, if the column "ID" (of the second) contains the value of "ID" of the first, return the corresponding text, like this:

```
ID       Text
132CC32  Example 3
112AA52  Example 1
142BB42  Example 2
```

The first table is small, it contains few values, but the second one can have thousands.

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula as shown in image below,

• Formula used in cell **B7**

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH($A$2:$A$4,A7),$B$2:$B$4)
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: Tanks a lot,
It worked perfectly, I just worked a little harder to find this function in my language, but when I found it, it worked.

Comment: @LucasFernandes oh okay, since you wrote in `ENGLISH` i thought you need the formula in the same language, i wasn't aware, you could have about that, i could have shared in your language as well. And thank you for the feedback Glad it worked for you!